# Font looks completely different in Windows

Tags: html, css, fonts

A client is using the PT Sans Regular font on their website and complaining that certain letters, like capital D, are being cut off at the top. I've confirmed that it's happening in all browsers on Windows. IE11, Chrome and Firefox. It looks fine on Mac. The problem persists when I change the font size, weight, line-height, etc. I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

[image: PT Sans Regular font is different on Windows]

Comment: Where did you get the font? Not all webfonts are created equal. Groups like typekit put a lot of work into their font rendering.

Comment: Might be `overflow: hidden`, but I don't know what that would work on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Please convert your font again with all web supportive fonts format's and used it.
For conversion font I mostly used the below url:
http://www.fontconverter.org/

Write custom font face in style sheet to render the font.